# Can emails be sent from PowerBuilder 12.5 without external applications?

Tags: html, email, powerbuilder

Is it possible to send emails using PowerBuilder 12.5 without external applications? These would be from, say, mickey.mouse@gmail.com to donald.duck@yahoo.co.uk with a subject and MS Word style, so rich text or HTML style.

The system is running on Windows, though either 7 or 10...

All help very much appreciated.

Comment: No external applications including Windows API?

Comment: Call me a novice. How would API work please?

Comment: Sorry for pestering, the system seems to have fixed itself, which is probably the most useless answer I could give. Unsure why it stopped and unsure why it started again...

Answer (score 4):

Try this example. It uses SMTP to talk directly to the mail server. The MAPI example above interacts with Outlook which would violate your no external programs rule.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/pbnismtp.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example for Powerbuilder 11.5, using mailSession objects.  The mail software you use must be MAPI compliant.

```
mailSession             mSes
mailReturnCode          mRet
mailMessage             mMsg
mailFileDescription     mAttach

// Create a mail session
mSes = create mailSession

// Log on to the session
mRet = mSes.mailLogon()
IF mRet <> mailReturnSuccess! THEN
    MessageBox("Mail", "Mail error")
    RETURN
END IF

// Populate the mailMessage structure
mMsg.Subject = "My own subject"
mMsg.Recipient[1].name = "recipient@domain.com"
mMsg.Notetext = ''
mAttach.FileType = mailAttach!
mAttach.PathName = gs_intrastat_rep + "\" + ls_filename[ll_i]
mAttach.FileName =  gs_intrastat_rep + "\" + ls_filename[ll_i]
mAttach.Position = len(mMsg.notetext) - 1       
mMsg.AttachmentFile[1] = mAttach

// Send the mail
mRet = mSes.mailSend(mMsg)
IF mRet = mailReturnSuccess! THEN
    MessageBox("Mail Sent", "Message sent successfully" )
ELSE
    MessageBox("Mail not Sent", "Impossible to send mail" )
    RETURN
END IF

mSes.mailLogoff()
DESTROY mSes
```

Comment: Just my $0.02. I used MAPI with PB 5 and Windows 3.1. It was a nightmare. An easier solution was the external command line SMTP tool BLAT. It is easy to configure on the fly, simple to invoke, powerful, flexible, predictable, and free. It can be copied into the same folder as EXE and PBD. No installation required. https://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/

Comment: PB5 and Windows 3.1?  That was have been last century then.  Personnaly, I didn't encounter any problems using MAPI (today PB 11.5 and Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many examples you can find by searching online with the term: 'email powerbuilder'.  One good choice would be the free code examples from Roland Smith at topwizprogramming.com (look for email smpt).